# Access to Area 51 Private Beta Commitment made under different User ID that can't OpenID

Tags: support, area-51, openid, stack-exchange, commitment-phase

I signed up a commitment to the Theoretical Computer Science Area 51 under an email address that can't OpenID. I then sign in with my Google OpenID and don't see the commitment.

I log out and then try to click through the email address validation link and sign in with a new (just created) MyOpenID account under that email address for which the email address's own domain has no OpenID of its own.

This just creates yet another user account under a different user ID number, despite the matching email address and the clicking through the email address verification. The commitment is not visible on this new user ID's page.

I want to get into the Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange site that I signed on to participate in during the Private Beta. How can I do that?

And why is this made so complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you *didn't* follow the special link in the private beta invite email, which contains a special access token. It looks something like this:

[image]

**If you don't follow this link in the private beta email**, bad things can happen.

Beyond that, email team@stackexchange.com for specifics.

Comment: I got no such email... :(     
It does show my commitment on the user page for the user I can't log in as, though.